# How to extract unique data from a column in google sheets with corresponding values using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet with 35 columns and 1000+ rows. I want to extract only unique data from column number 5 with all the remaining 34 corresponding values to a new sheet. My row number 4 is date column so, the date should be the latest one when the unique value of column number 5 is extracted to the new sheet.

Comment: Cool! How do you plan to do that? :)

Comment: I don't have a working code, but you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) for the functions you needed.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question for you on Quora, but since no one else has gotten an answer here either I figured I'd double post it to give some further help for future Google searches.

The code below is a basic template that should solve your problems, but I’ll go into further detail to help you understand what it is doing and how it works.

```
=FILTER(
    SORT(Work!A:D,1,FALSE),
    SORT(Work!A:A,1,FALSE) = UNIQUE(SORT(Work!A:A,1,FALSE))
 )

=FILTER(range to be filtered, conditions that dictate what will pass the filter, more conditions)

=SORT(Range, by column, (true = ascending,false = descending (reverse) order))
```

So, we apply a FILTER and use the first SORT to dictate that the entire sheet is to be sorted in reverse order (I used reverse order because my dates came in sequentially, as is typical from form-entered data or for most standard spreadsheet setups). If your sheet is setup in reverse date order already, then you can drop all of the SORT formulas and say something like:

```
=FILTER(Work!A:D,Work!A:A = UNIQUE(Work!A:A))
```

Now, in my example I wrote:

```
SORT(Work!A:D,1,FALSE)
```

The important part to note here is that since this is the section of the filter which defines the range we wish to return, you must specify all of the rows that you want to see in your output. I put Work!A:D because that was the size of the sheet I was working with. Since you are using 35 columns I believe you would use A:AI.

Next, you identify only the column that you wish to be sorted uniquely, and you do this by specifying SORT(Sheet!DesiredColumn:DesiredColumn,1,FALSE). Each part of the sheet must be sorted the same direction to get the correct results.
Finally, we are comparing the sorted column to a UNIQUE array of that same sorted column, which is why `SORT(Work!A:A,1,FALSE) = UNIQUE(SORT(Work!A:A,1,FALSE))`.

This is just comparing the row to a unique version of itself, and will only return the unique options, in your specified order, to get the most recent entries first.
By feeding the uniquely sorted entries as exclusionary parameters into the main filter range, you will be able to retrieve the entire row for each unique entry in the desired column.
So, your final formula will probably look something like:

```
=FILTER(
    SORT(Sheet1!A:AI,1,FALSE),
    SORT(Sheet1!E:E,1,FALSE) = UNIQUE(SORT(Sheet1!E:E,1,FALSE))
 )
```

where Sheet1 is the name of the sheet you are sorting the data from.
Hopefully that helps you with your data problems now, and in the future.